# Do I have to re-init git-flow repository after every clone?

Tags: git-flow

I have a repository where I'm using git flow. I initialized the git flow, but when I clone it I need to run `git flow init` again. Is there an automated way of doing this!?

At initialization I have to setup:

- develop, production branches
- features, releases and bugfix prefix
- version prefix.

I know this configuration by heart but another developers may not know and typing it by hand may be error prone.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer for this?

Comment: No, I'm not using git flow, I'm using a simplified form of flow (only feature and bug branches) and raw git commands :/